# Light switch to quickly toggle power on and off for LED control

Tags: electrical, light-fixture

I installed an led chandelier that is controlled by a remote, which can change the color temperature and dim it. The light came with a 120VAC/24VDC driver.

The device came with little instruction, but the manufacturers (who aren't communicative) told me you can change the color temperature from the wall switch by quickly toggling it on and off. Other folks on Amazon say they have used dimmer switches to control the device, but without a better understanding of the driver, I'm afraid to connect it to a dimmer. I'd like to control it from the wall switch most of the time.

Is there a particular type of wall switch that can quickly toggle itself on and off to change color temperature? Is there a particular type of dimmer that works with a driver like this?

Comment: Be very wary of what you connect to 120/240. Of the instructions are that bad and manufacturer that hard to talk to, I'd be really concerned about it being tested, listed and safe for mains power.

Comment: "wall switch that can quickly toggle itself" you'd probably need a smart switch and some sort of computer control/home automation to "control itself". OTOH, I've got a bathroom fan that senses humidity level and turns itself on/off when crossing its preset humidity level. I can turn the fan _on_ by flipping the switch off, then turning it back on within (5, it think) seconds, and I put it back in auto-mode by doing the same. It sounds like that same "Off/On" switch flip is what will cause your lights to change temperature. Give that a try.

Comment: And I second @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact's concerns - check to enure that your switch is UL (or your country's approval board) listed and that it's a legit listing, not just that they've printed the mark on the switch to make it look good.

Comment: you would want a control where the dimmer and on/off are broken out separate, instead of say a single large knob, look for a little switch and a slider.

Comment: Can you post photos of the driver please?

Comment: Usually it's "quickly" as in "average person throwing average wall switch off and on again at leisure pace", probably about a second or two. It's like mouse click vs double click - you don't need a special button, you just click the regular button twice. BTW I think it's on-off-on, not off-on-off.

Answer (score 1):

That's a recent trend in LED lights; the driver changes to give you different color temperatures or even colors by "coding" it with the switch. You don't need anything special, a standard toggle switch is fine. You flip the switch on for the first level, on and off and back on to change to the second level, on-off-on-off-on for the third, on-off-on-off-on-off-on for the 4th (if there is one). This type typically is NOT suitable for dimming, mine is not. Basically if the instructions do not EXPLICITLY say you can use a dimmer, you cannot.